# show posts wordpress AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Hi i m trying to just show posts when i click the button

and just dont get what m i missing.

```
function load_more_ar(post_id){
   jQuery("#loading-animation").show();
   var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>';
   jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            "action": "load-arts" ,
            'post_id': post_id

            },

        success: function(response) {
            jQuery("#category-post-content").html(response);
            jQuery("#loading-animation").hide();
            return false;
        }
    });
 }
```

and thats a PHP

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load-arts', 'load_more_arts' );
add_action(' wp_ajax_nopriv_load-arts' , 'load_more_arts');
function load_more_arts() {
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'articles',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_id' => $post_id
);


$posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
echo $post_id;
echo $post -> name;


}

die();
}
```

i couldnt find some decent tutorial for this specific task.
can i get any help here or at least references for tutorials?